# What exactly is the Poya-gun?

Tags: occultic-nine

In every episode so far, Ryoka shoots/zaps Yuta with her Poya-gun, to which Yuta usually exclaims "POYA-GUN! NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!"

What exactly is the Poya-gun? It seems too advanced for her to have made it, but everyone writes it off as being a totally normal thing when she zaps Yuta with it. At first, I thought it might be occult-related, but seeing as how Yuta does not believe in the occult, it wouldn't make sense for one of his closest friends to use an occultic object in front of him on a daily basis.

Also, I have no reason to suspect that Yuta is not human, so his recovery is a bit superhuman if the Poya-gun is like a taser.

Comment: I think it's just a toy and Yuta simulate an electrocution when Ryoka zaps him.
But currently, I did not see any explaination in the anime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The true nature of the Poya-gun was revealed in Episode 10. Major spoilers below:

> The Poya-gun is actually named the Wardenclyffe Gun and plays a major role in the goals of the New World System. Essentially, it is used to zap people in order to recharge their Scandium to preserve their astral projections. Its appearance is actually a miniature version of the [Wardenclyffe tower](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wardenclyffe_Tower).

Answer (score 2):

It's an electricity based self defense stun gun, comedically shaped like a retro style ray gun, likely of a not very high amperage as it doesn't seem to have much of a disabling factor on Gamon. People probably don't react because it's anime and nobody really cares that the 'main' is being abused by his friend. Of course, stun guns (tasers) don't actually work like the show implies the 'Poya Gun' does (as tasers don't have ranged ability, relying on you touching the arc to the victim for it to actually work.)